# How to safely command an axis camera with curl?

Tags: curl, https

I have an Axis PTZ camera I want to command using CURL.

I know this command line works :

```
curl http://LOGIN:PASSWORD@IP/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?rpan=10
```

But, as you can see, le login/password are clearly written in the URL.

So I tried in HTTPS with :

```
curl -k https://LOGIN:PASSWORD@IP/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?rpan=10
```

... where the -k ignore certificate warnings.

It works too, but I want to be sure that my login/password are encrypted using this way.

Anyone can confirm ? (or give a way to command this camera safely)

Edit : well, I just edit my post to "bump"... :-°

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. I believe URL parameters are encrypted with https but I can't find anything about credentials in the URL

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your login and password are encrypted when using HTTPS - even if they are transmitted as GET data embedded directly in the URL. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted) for more info.

However, by specifying `-k` as an option to *curl* you are essentially disabling its [certificate validation features](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html). This makes it prone to [man-in-the-middle-attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907718/5717099). A successful attack of this kind would render your entire connection (including your credentials) decipherable.

Comment: Bother to explain the downvote? - I'm always eager to learn, should there be anything wrong with the above...