# Capture and edit TCP/UDP packets in C#

Tags: c#, packet-sniffers, network-analysis

I'm trying to create a tool, which would append/edit something inside specific packets, before they get sent to the specific website.

For now I was using Wpe Pro to apply this filter.

Is there something similar in C# to create this tool?

Comment: Even if this is a bit broad, I am interested in possible ways too. I guess we are talking about editing TCP/UDP packets. Point of interest is also editing packets when using SSL connections.

Comment: Yes im talking about TCP/UDP packets :)

Comment: Since you will have to use [Pcap](https://www.winpcap.org/), you might want to use [this](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) .NET implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not really a general way to do this. There are multiple possibilities you have to consider and see if they fit your situation. For example you can edit a packet that is send using HTTP by using [Pcap.NET](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net) (as said in the comments) easily. There are dozens of examples out there on the web that will guide you in modifying packets using Pcap, for example [this discussion](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/349978)  on the official Pcap.NET forums.

However, if the packet is using HTTPS (SSL/TLS) then the payload, which is the actual data being send, will be encrypted and this could be bypassed; if one/multiple [precondition(s) of SSL are broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907718/2058541) or by using a tool like [sslstrip (python)](https://moxie.org/software/sslstrip/). Note that sslstrip will try to force the socket to be send through HTTP even if HTTPS is requested and this is not guaranteed to work.

Personally I will always try to avoid touching the sockets even anything network related. Especially when it involves HTTPS, because as you probably understand by now, this is pretty hard to bypass. I have no idea what program you are attempting to break, but I felt like it would benefit to this answer.

For HTTP, one could easily create a simple program that [hooks](https://easyhook.github.io/) the [Windows Socket API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock). You should be looking into the [send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx) function and possibly even the [recv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx) (receive) function. You can modify the payload as you wish or even replace it with another payload, if desired.
Note that data that is send through the winsock.send function is already encrypted (if SSL/TLS is being used) as the application will handle layers 7 (application layer), 6 (presentation layer) and 5 (session layer, this is [where SSL gets applie](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19681/where-does-ssl-encryption-take-place)d) of the OSI model. [Winsock is a bridge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms882974.aspx) between layer 5 and 4.

For HTTPS you can still use hooking, but you must hook the part of the application where it handles the connections and make sure you apply your (modified) payload before it initializes the connection / sets the payload. This may sound hard to do, put it is actually pretty easy to do, if you are willing to learn and have some time.

Comment: The goal (at least for me) is to handle general browsers behaviour with some data. If facing that much problems with SSL the alternative way would only be hooking up into the browser itself. But as there are many different of them I would need to code this for multiple browsers = much work to do. I was hoping grabbing the packets would group all of them on one place... :/

Comment: If the browser visits the website using HTTP you can use any of the described methods but if it visits the website using HTTPS you either need to have the master certificate or hook the browser in order to decrypt, modify and (re-)encrypt the payload.

Comment: Hmm not solved in the way I hoped for but I guess with this comment we are done in here. Thanks for clearing that out. Ill set the reward as far as the countdown went to 0 (22 hours).