# Verify Peer in python

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, pyopenssl

I am trying to create a socket connection using python.

Here is my python code...

```
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.settimeout(config['timeout'])
self.socket.connect((config['host'], config['port']))

self.ssl = ssl.wrap_socket(
    self.socket,
    certfile=config['certificate'],
    keyfile=config['key']
)
```

It didn't work as remote server's certificate seems to be self-signed or missing from trust store. I am new to python and could not figure out how to disable verify_peer in python so connection could work.

I have working code in php...

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'local_cert' => $config['certificate'],
        'local_pk' => $config['key']
    ]
]);

$socket = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://secure.test.com:700',
    $errno, $errstr, $config['timeout'],
    STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context
);
```

Setting `'verify_peer' => false` helps to establish the connection. How can i do something like that in python?

openssl debug

```
openssl s_client -connect secure.test.com:700

verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1

verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

Please help and suggest. Thanks

Comment: *"Setting `verify_peer => false` helps to establish the connection. How can i do something like that in python?"* - Very bad idea; see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html).

Comment: *"It didn't work as remote server's certificate seems to be self-signed or missing from trust store..."* - Which is it? The use case affects the answer. Please post the URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: @jww Thanks for your help. I've edited the question with more details. I am getting this error: `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate` already tried to re-acquire the current certificate via a Linux command `openssl s_client -connect secure.test.com:700:`

Comment: `secure.test.com:700` times out for me. Port 700 appears to be unavailable from the outside world, but port 443 is accessible and has a server on it. The Issuer's CommonName is `CN=Network Solutions OV Server CA 2`. You need to install [Network Solution's CA Root](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/where-can-i-locate-the-network-solutions-nsprotect-root-and-intermediate-certificate-files/) in your local trust store (the one Python uses). You won't need `verify_peer => false` because the path from the server to the CA will validate.

Comment: @jww How to import ca root in local trust store so python can use it. I am new to python. Sorry.

Comment: See [18.2. ssl — TLS/SSL wrapper for socket objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) in the manual.

Comment: @jww can you please suggest, how to import ca root in local trust store so python can use it. This would solve the issue.  Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling certificate validation can simply be done by adding `cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_NONE`. But, just **disabling certificate validation is a very bad idea since you know open to [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907581/ssl-and-man-in-the-middle-misunderstanding)**.

Therefore you should check that the certificate is the expected one. With self-signed certificates (and others too) you can check for example that the received certificate matches the expected certificate fingerprint, like in the following code:

```
import socket
import ssl
import hashlib

dst = ('www.paypal.com',443)
fp_expected = '0722d46c216327bab8075f5db57ebed64d80e6699204c249c3f6ea9cc281c15b'

# connect to the target with TCP
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(dst)

# upgrade the socket to SSL without checking the certificate
s = ssl.wrap_socket(s,cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_NONE)

# get certificate, compute fingerprint and check against expected value
cert_bin = s.getpeercert(True)
fp = hashlib.sha256()
fp.update(cert_bin)
assert(fp.hexdigest() == fp_expected)
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I am stuck with this error.  `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate` and `verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate` when i run `openssl s_client -connect secure.test.com:700 -key client.key -cert client.crt` so i thought to disable certificate checking.

Comment: @seoppc: the code above can be used to verify at least that the server certificate is the expected if it is self-signed or somehow broken. But it there should be  proper certificate + chain then maybe you are doing it wrong from start: it could for example be that the server requires you to use SNI extension to get the right certificate and chain which a simple wrap_socket will not achieve. Note that I cannot test this with s_client since secure.test.com:700 is not accessible from my location, i.e. already the TCP connect fails.