# What's the difference between MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL and MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT?

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

This is how I usually connect to a MySQL database using SSL:

```
$db = mysqli_init();
mysqli_ssl_set(
    $db,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    '/etc/ssl/my-certs/ssl-ca.crt.pem',
    NULL,
    NULL
);
mysqli_real_connect(
    $db,
    'db.example.com',
    'john',
    '123456',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL
);
```

From what I understand, the `MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL` flag is necessary to make [`mysqli::real_connect`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php) connect to the server using SSL.

Today I stumbled upon the documentation for [`mysqli::options`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php), and noticed that it accepts `MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` as an option, but, alas, its description is blank. So, I wonder:

1. When do I need to add `mysqli_options($db, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);`?
2. When do I need to use the `MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL` flag?
3. When will I need to set both of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` (true) used when you want to verify server certificate against well known authorities to ensure that this is connection to trusted host. Do not use it if you have self-signed certificate on server.
2. `MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL` must be always used when you need to encrypt connection.
3. When you have on mysql-server certificate provided by authorities and want encryption + [MITM-attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907581/ssl-and-man-in-the-middle-misunderstanding) protection use both `MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` and `MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL`.

Comment: Suppose I omit `mysqli_ssl_set(...)` and instead, I add a self-signed CA certificate to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`, and run `sudo update-ca-certificates` to add my self-signed certificate to the trusted store. Can I set `MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` to `true`?

Comment: You *can* verify the server certificate even if you use self-signed certs, you just need to add that cert to the correct trust store. “Well known authorities” are only well-known because they’re in that trust store by default.

Comment: @Flux You need to run `sudo update-ca-certificates` on every host where your script supposed to run. This is not good idea.

Comment: Is `MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` set to `true` by default?

Comment: @Flux I think this is another interesting question with a high voteup potential. Vote for answer and create another one :)

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk Follow-up question about `MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299690/

Comment: Where did you get the information regarding `MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT`?

Comment: @Flux Information about `MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` from PHP `mysqli` documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk Isn't that the same webpage that I already linked to in the question body?